# How to redirect a non-virtual host from http to https

Tags: http, redirect, https, httpd.conf

I want to redirect http to https for a domain on an apache server by modifying the httpd.conf file. The domain is the server name it is NOT a virtual host. All examples I have found are for a virtual host. How can I accomplish that?

Do I put code in the ''?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Redirect rule in httpd.conf outside VirtualHost.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```